# React-routing v6 can't pass component props to mapStateToProps

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I'm new to react and trying to make a simple project.
My problem is I'm trying to pass component props to mapStateToProps and I can't do it.
I read that i should pass ownProps to mapStateToProps as parameter however it is always empty.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VvKz.png)

```
<Routes>
    <Route path="/" exact={true} element={<CollectionsOverview />} />
    <Route path="/:id" element={<CollectionPage />} /> 
</Routes>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8Z2l.png)

```
    const CollectionPage = ({ collection }) => {
    const { id } = useParams();
    this.props.id = id;
    const { title, items } = collection;
    return (
        <CollectionPageContainer>
            <Title>{title}</Title>
            <ItemsContainer>
                {
                    items.map(item => <CollectionItem key={item['id']} item={item} />)
                }
            </ItemsContainer>
        </CollectionPageContainer>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
    console.log(ownProps);
    return {
        collection: selectCollection(ownProps.id)(state)
    }
}
```

ownProps is empty object here.My question is how can i pass properties to mapStateToProps or what am i doing wrong here

Comment: Do *not* put code in pictures. Copy&paste the relevant code into code blocks. By posting code as images: 1) It is impossible to copy&paste which means people that want to help must re-type the whole code which takes a lot of time while a fix might just be fixing a typo 2) It makes it impossible for blind or vision-impaired people to access the question.

Comment: why do you need mapStateToProps?

Comment: @MWO i want to select collection by it's id and can't pass id to mapStateToProps

Comment: you dont even call mapStateToProps, why do you want to use it? do you use redux?

Comment: @MWO yes i connect it with my component i just didn't copy that part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be obvious from the component use that absolutely no props are being passed to it from the route.

```
<Route
  path="/:id"
  element={<CollectionPage />} // <-- no props passed to CollectionPage
/>
```

The `connect` HOC however is injecting the `collection` prop, but `ownProps` is simply an empty object.

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  console.log(ownProps);
  return {
    collection: selectCollection(ownProps.id)(state)
  }
}
```

The problem here is that your selector function appears to need the `id` route match param in order to work, and that simply just isn't available until you are in the function component scope via the `useParams` hook.

You've a couple options now.

1. Use a wrapper component to "sip" the `id` from the params and pass as a prop to `CollectionPage` component

   ```
   const CollectionPageWrapper = (props) => {
     const { id } = useParams();
     return <CollectionPage id={id} {...props} />
   };

   ...

   const CollectionPage = ({ collection }) => {
     const { title, items } = collection;
     return (
       <CollectionPageContainer>
         <Title>{title}</Title>
         <ItemsContainer>
           {items.map(item => <CollectionItem key={item.id} item={item} />)}
         </ItemsContainer>
       </CollectionPageContainer>
     );
   };

   const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
     collection: selectCollection(ownProps.id)(state)
   };

   export default connect(mapStateToProps)(CollectionPageWrapper);
   ```

   ...

   ```
   <Route path="/:id" element={<CollectionPage />} />
   ```
2. Move the `selectCollection` selector logic into `CollectionPage` and use the `useSelector` hook and pass in the selector with `id`

   ```
   const CollectionPage = () => {
     const { id } = useParams();
     const collection = useSelector(selectCollection(id));

     const { title, items } = collection;

     return (
       <CollectionPageContainer>
         <Title>{title}</Title>
         <ItemsContainer>
           {items.map(item => <CollectionItem key={item.id} item={item} />)}
         </ItemsContainer>
       </CollectionPageContainer>
     );
   };

   export default CollectionPage;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

`this.props.id` does not exist on react functional components. You did it right by destructuring with `useParams`. But in `ownProps` you dont have a `id` property. So you cant pass it in `selectCollection` like that. You can have a look at [this demo App](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-redux-forked-vkism?file=/CollectionPage.js:596-606). Hope it helps you understand how you could set all up.

```
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

const CollectionPage = ({ collection }) => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  //this.props.id = id;
  console.log(id);
  const { title, items } = collection;

  return (
    <div>
      <div>{title}</div>
      <div>
        {items.map((item) => (
          <div key={item["id"]} item={item} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  console.log(ownProps.collection.items[0].id); //this is how you can access an  ID from your items
  /*     return {
      collection: selectCollection(ownProps.id)(state)
  } */
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(CollectionPage);
```